# Finding unique dataframes from list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

I have a list of dataframes (can be all different sizes) and I want to quickly find all the unique dataframes within that list.

I originally wanted to use: (But this fails due to the dataframes being of different sizes)

```py
_,idx=np.unique(np.array([x.values for x in df_list]),axis=0, return_index=True)

desired_list=[df_list[x] for  x in idx]
```

I then put this together but is incredibly efficient when the dataset becomes large:

```py
desired_list=[[x.equals(y) for x in df_list] for y in df_list] #List of booleans - This is the ineffiency
str_list = [str(d) for d in desired_list] #Turn the elements into strings

unique_pos = np.unique(str_list, return_index=True)[1] #Get index positions of all unique strings

final_list = []
for u in unique_pos:
    cen = df_list[u]
    final_list.append(cen)
```

Is there another way I can go about getting this done in a more efficient way?

Comment: whats the commonality between the dataframes?

Comment: They have the exact same columns, the only difference is there could be different number of rows in each dataframe

Comment: you could just concat and do `duplicated` across the entire dataframe just remove the index column (which will be the key of the dict) to view whats duplicated and whats not

Comment: Its not the rows themselves that I want to get rid of duplicates but the whole dataframe its part of. So two dataframes can have the same row but as long as they have other rows that are different then I want to keep both dataframes in the list. I hope that makes sense.